# 404 route issues with React Router and Suspense

Tags: reactjs, react-router, lazy-loading, react-suspense, no-match

I'm trying to use lazy loading, with Suspense, from React 16.12.0. I'm also using React Router 5.1.2.

It's the first time I'm using Suspense and I haven't managed to find a proper way to load a `404/NoMatch` without causing other issues.

My code looks like this:

```
import Component1 from 'path'
import Component2 from 'path'
import NoMatchPage from 'path'
const Component3 = lazy(()=>import('path'));
const Component4 = lazy(()=>import('path'));

<Router>
   <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/route-1" component={Component1}/>
        <Route exact path="/route-2" component={Component2}/>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>
            <Route exact path="/route-3" component={Component3}/>
            <Route exact path="/route-4" component={Component4}/>
        </Suspense>
        <Route component={NoMatchPage}/>
   <Switch>
</Router>
```

- Written like this, the `NoMatchPage` component will never be shown.
- Written inside the Suspense, as the last child, will render the `NoMatchPage` component on any route, placed after the component that should be rendered on that path.
- Written just above the Suspense, will render the `NoMatchPage` component on any route, placed before the component that should be rendered on that path.

I've checked the official documentation and a lot practical examples, but I've found nothing that could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

from [the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) that i read, there is an example that *Switch* component is working inside *Suspense* component. So maybe for your issue, you can try to move *Switch* component into *Suspense* component (order of component *Suspense* is higher than component *Switch*). Below is an example.

```
  <Router>
    <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      </Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </Router>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have figured it out, but try to nest the suspense inside the route like this and do it for each route you want to have suspense fallback on:

```
<Route exact path="/route-3"/>
 <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
  <Component3/>
 </Suspense>
</Route>
```